# Can you preload libraries in Python or precompile a .py file?

Tags: python, optimization, python-requests

I need to import a requests library at each call of a Python file that is called once every second. However, importing the requests takes two seconds every time I run the file.

```
time /usr/local/bin/python3 -c"import requests"
real    0m 1.86s
user    0m 1.55s
sys 0m 0.09s
```

Is there a way to decrease this import time? If not, could I write a binary file that would do the same thing much faster?

Comment: why don't you import the requests library inside your python script

Comment: How long does it take to run python3 -c”pass” ?

Comment: @barny time /usr/local/bin/python3 -c"pass"
real 0m 0.21s
user 0m 0.14s
sys 0m 0.04s

Comment: @ArpitSolanki I did the above was just an example to show how slow it is.

Comment: @ArsenalFanatic I don't think it can be reduced much

Comment: I get very different figures here (on average real 0m0.101s), and this is on a 6+ years desktop (no ssd) that was already barely above entry-level new.  FWIW python modules are compiled to `.pyc` files if the `.pyc` file does not exist or is older than the `.py` file, but I made another try after removing the .pyc from my py3 requests install and I still didn't get higher than 0m0.187s (real).  Problem might be with your system and/or install. NB : for    time python3 -c "pass" I get  0m0.023s real.